# Is there any way to get reference of tapped view using 3D touch?

Tags: ios, swift, touch, 3dtouch

I am using below code:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
{
    guard let indexPath = self.detailedTableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
        let cell = self.detailedTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return nil }

}
```

I am getting the wrong index path using above code.

I am wondering if, is there any way to get tapped view reference of tag?

Comment: Try this 
CGPoint cellPostion = [self.tableview convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:cellPostion];

Comment: This is also giving the wrong index.